# How to add the suffix 'd' in the names of the OpenSSL libraries?

Tags: c++, build, openssl, visual-studio-2017, configure

I'm trying to build the last stable version of OpenSSL (1.1.1g) in windows (vs2017). Everything works fine in release.

But as we need to both release and debug libraries to cohexist in the same folder, we must add the suffix '**d**' to the library/dll names.

I have read both INSTALL and NOTES.WIN, but I couldn't find any information related to this possibility.

Is it possible to add the suffix '**d**' to the openssl output file names in debug?

Answer (score 1):

If you are building OpenSSL using CMake (For CMake file see [here](https://github.com/viaduck/openssl-cmake) and [here](https://github.com/janbar/openssl-cmake)), you can simply:

```
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
```

For more see: [cmake: add "d" suffix for debug build of static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672264/cmake-add-d-suffix-for-debug-build-of-static-library)

If not I believe your options are limited, unless you feel like editing make/name files

Comment: I don't think OpenSSL can be compiled with CMake (At least the official repository version) . I know this option, but as OpenSSL does not use CMake to handle builds it cannot be used. I will check both links

Comment: I linked 2 community-created CMake repositories. So it is definitely possible to compile OpenSSL using CMake, but you are correct in that OpenSSL does not supply the CMake themselves

Comment: Yes. I saw both links and they aim to deliver a CMake build to OpenSSL. Thanks for mentioning it. But I was really looking for a way to define the 'd' prefix in the official build.